# Play a sequence of 360-degree videos in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am looking to play a sequence of 360-degree videos in Unity through a C# script. Each video has a corresponding audio of the same duration (extracted using Ffmpeg)and which should play in sync with the video. I also want to display a grey screen of 1 second duration between each video.

I have tried a similar script which was provided in stackoverflow (with some slight modifications) that can play normal videos in sequence. The script uses a RawImage on a canvas to render the video. I am trying to modify it to a Sphere instead of RawImage, then use the flipverticals shader on the sphere and render the 360-video to the sphere. Not sure about this approach.

```
// Raw Image to Show Video Images [Assign from the Editor]
public RawImage image;
public List<VideoClip> videoClipList;
private List<VideoPlayer> videoPlayerList;
private int videoIndex = 0;

// Assign the Texture from Video to RawImage to be displayed
image.texture = videoPlayerList[videoIndex].texture;
```

I expect to be able to play a sequence of 360-degree videos - the number and names of the video should be supplied at run-time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    private GameObject textureObj; // Your sphere with a MeshRenderer
    private Texture2D storeTexture; // Just a texture from assets thats use to transport the stream
    private Renderer textureRenderer;

    private void Start() {
        this.storeTexture = videoPlayerList[videoIndex].texture;

        this.textureRenderer = this.textureObj.GetComponent<Renderer>();
        this.textureRenderer.material.mainTexture = this.storeTexture;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @Musaka. It helped me progress further.

Comment: @AmitHirway be sure to leave a thumbs up :D

Comment: How do I give a thumbs up? Where can I find it?

Comment: You can see a number on the left of my answer, you should always press the upper arrow of the number if you found the answer/question usefull :D